# Set country from custom cart controller

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, controllers, magento-ce

I try to set the country from my custom cart controller with the following function:

```
public function setCountryAction()
{
    $country = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

    $quote->getBillingAddress()->setCountryId($country);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($country);
    $quote->save();

    // print $quote->getBillingAddress()->getCountryId();
}
```

The print at the end of the function contains the expected result but unfortunately the country is not actually saved to the quote.

When I change the country from the checkout, go back to the cart and do the action again, strangely enough it works perfectly.

So the problem only exists with a new, empty session.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965620/magento-save-quote-address-on-cart-addaction-using-observer. if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found! This issue has to do with the 'Default country' option in the OneStepCheckout extension.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$quote->save();` or before it try

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->save();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->save();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but this is unfortunately not working.